ReactQuery v4 local storage persistance
I'm using React Query v4 to cache API requests and persist them into local storage. My setup works fine for the first query, but subsequent queries with different updatingValue values are not persisted in local storage, even though they are being added to the query cache.
Here's the setup:
return useQuery({
   queryKey: ['myData', updatingValue],
   queryFn: () => fetchData(updatingValue),
   cacheTime: CACHE_TIME_MS,
   staleTime: STALE_TIME_MS,
   select: (data) => select(data),
 });

When debugging the queryCache from React Query, I can see that all queries are correctly added to the queries object. For example:
add(query: Query<any, any, any, any>): void {
  if (!this.queriesMap[query.queryHash]) {
    this.queriesMap[query.queryHash] = query
    this.queries.push(query)
    this.notify({
      type: 'added',
      query,
    });
  }
}

However, in the local storage, only the first query is persisted, while subsequent queries with different updatingValue are not.
What I've tried:
Ensuring that queryKey is unique for each query.
Verifying that queries are added to the cache correctly.
Expected behavior:
Each query should persist in local storage, not just the first one.
After cleaning the local storage, next time the query is executed, again, it's saved into the local storage; but the following ones are not.

are you sure that the queries are in success state? Because only successful queries are persisted per default

yes, the data related to the non-persisted queries is shown on the screen after the request is successful @TkDodo

is there any way the query is not in success state, but the data is shown?

looking with the devtools, i can see that all the myData queries have the initialState status field equal to: loading instead of success;
The first one tho',  has  the success status;

further more, after the first query is deleted from the persistence layer(due to cacheTime being expired); i can see that the next query is persisted

if i trigger  an error or remove the query which is persisted in the local storage from the devtools, again, the next query will be persisted @TkDodo

Can it be the case that on the v4 we cannot have multiple data in the local storage for the same query function?

the best thing you can do is provide a minimal, runnable reproduction of your problem with either codesandbox or stackblitz.

@TkDodo found a possible solution, posted it as an answer

i can promise you we don't care about array or object at all. It's more likely that there is something non-serializable in your response, like maybe response headers from axios or something

After spending some time debugging, I discovered that React Query v4 struggles to persist cached queries when the query function returns a Promise<Array>. It appears React Query cannot differentiate between instances of arrays, causing issues with cache invalidation and persistence.
The solution is to wrap the array in an object. Instead of returning Promise<Array>, return an object like this:
export interface MyResponse {
  data: Array<MyType>;
}

By returning an object, React Query can properly handle the cache and ensure correct persistence across reloads. This approach resolved the issue for me.
